# Call to undefined function curl_init()

Tags: php, curl

I'm running XAMP on Windows XP Pro. I've enabled curl in PHP.INI en restarted my machine and Apache.

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

Still I get the following error in my php script:

> Call to undefined function curl_init()

File php_curl.dll is in C:\Program Files\xampp\php\ext and I have this line

```
extension_dir = "C:\Program Files\xampp\php\ext\"
```

Comment: Is cURL shown in the phpinfo output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay.dll` files in your PHP directory must be accessible from somewhere in your `PATH` variable for cURL to work with Apache. The easiest way to achieve this is to add your PHP directory to your `PATH` environment variable.